# Extract only raw ids from an Eloquent collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I need to get an **array of integers**, which will contain raw ids of Eloquent records. The following query

```
Quote::select('id')->get();
```

gets an eloquent collection instead of an array of integers. How to modify it, so it meets my requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Quote::get(['id'])->toArray();
```

Or:

```
Quote::all(['id'])->toArray();
```

Or:

```
DB::table('quote')->select('id')->get()->toArray();
```

Or:

```
Quote::pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, the last snippet worked like a charm

Comment: 3rd one helped me :)